# Issue with Intent java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity

Tags: java, android, xml

I am trying to build teacher assistant app. I tried to design my MainActivity with ImageViews and used Intent to go to next page.Whenever I try to click Image it displays following error

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: com.andisofttechnology.myapplication, PID: 9368
                  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.andisofttechnology.myapplication/com.andisofttechnology.myapplication.Student_Registartion}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'int java.util.List.size()' on a null object reference
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2778)
```

Here is what I tried in MainActivity.class

```
package com.andisofttechnology.myapplication;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private ImageView btnRegister;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



     ImageView btnRegister = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.btnRegister);

     btnRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         @Override
         public void onClick(View v) {
             Intent Register = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Student_Registartion.class);
             startActivity(Register);
         }
     });
```

Student_Registration.class

```
package com.andisofttechnology.myapplication;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.Toast;
/*import java.util.ArrayList;*/

public class Student_Registartion extends AppCompatActivity {



    Activity activity = this;
    Spinner spinner;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_student__registartion);

        spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, AppBase.divisions);
        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);

        Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonSAVE);
        assert btn != null;
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                saveToDatabase(v);
            }
        });
    }


    public void saveToDatabase(View view) {
        EditText name = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit_name);
        EditText roll = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.roll);
        EditText register = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.register);
        EditText contact = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.contact);
        String classSelected = spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();

        if(name.getText().length()<2||roll.getText().length()==0||register.getText().length()<2||
                contact.getText().length()<2||classSelected.length()<2)
        {
            AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(activity);
            alert.setTitle("Invalid");
            alert.setMessage("Insufficient Data");
            alert.setPositiveButton("OK", null);
            alert.show();
            return;
        }

        String qu = "INSERT INTO STUDENT VALUES('" +name.getText().toString()+ "'," +
                "'" + classSelected +"',"+
                "'" + register.getText().toString().toUpperCase() +"',"+
                "'" + contact.getText().toString() +"',"+
                "" + Integer.parseInt(roll.getText().toString()) +");";
        Log.d("Student Reg" , qu);
        AppBase.handler.execAction(qu);
        qu = "SELECT * FROM STUDENT WHERE regno = '" + register.getText().toString() +  "';";
        Log.d("Student Reg" , qu);
        if(AppBase.handler.execQuery(qu)!=null)
        {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Student Added", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            this.finish();
        }
    }
}
```

MainActivity.XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"

        >


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/btnCheck"

            android:layout_width="180dp"
            android:layout_height="250dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="11dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="11dp"
            android:src="@drawable/attend200" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/btnSchedul"

            android:layout_width="180dp"


            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/btnCheck"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/btnCheck"
            android:layout_below="@+id/btnCheck"
            android:layout_marginTop="22dp"
            android:src="@drawable/schedule" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/btnRegister"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:focusable="true"

            android:layout_width="170dp"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/btnSchedul"
            android:layout_marginLeft="11dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="11dp"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/btnSchedul"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btnSchedul"
            android:src="@drawable/profile" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/btnNote"

            android:layout_width="150dp"

            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:layout_above="@+id/btnSchedul"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/btnRegister"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/btnRegister"
            android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
            android:src="@drawable/notes" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/btnNote"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView4"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView4"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:text="@string/davomat"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView5"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView5"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_marginLeft="13dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="13dp"
            android:text="@string/eslatmalar"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/btnSchedul"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/btnSchedul"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/btnSchedul"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
            android:text="@string/dars_jadvali"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
```

............................................................................................................

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Showing Error :Attempt to invoke interface method 'int java.util.List.size()' on a null object reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36433964/showing-error-attempt-to-invoke-interface-method-int-java-util-list-size-on)

Comment: I think the problem is that you havent yet added the activity to manifest

Comment: Ananthu, activity added to manifest.However,the same issue displaying((

Answer (score 2):

AppBase.divisions is probably null here. You need to initialise it before adding it to the adaptor

Answer (score 0):

Do not create adapter until get `AppBase.divisions` value, to avoid this error, you could also initialize `AppBase.divisions` using `new` operator